# Django unit testing view with a decorator

Tags: python, unit-testing, django-testing

I am writing a unit test for an already existing project on developer resp. However, I am new to Django.test modules. Here are certain things I find quite puzzling If there is someone kind enough to explain this piece of code to me.
`

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse, resolve
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class TestUrls(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
       #creating a test user in testDB
        self.client = Client() 
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser', password='testpass')
        self.client = Client()

    
    def test_path_resolved(self):
        url = reverse('pathname')
        self.client.login(username='testuser', password='testpass')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

`

Why I created a test user and logged in using it because this path's view has a @login_required decorator.

I am wondering If this test code is testing If the PATH is resolved or is it just testing can it be reached when login_required decorator is met.